# Is there any verb that doesn't have negative form?

Tags: verbs, negation

I'm wondering if a verb exists without a negative form. I mean if it does not have it at all or the negative form of it is somehow meaningless.

for example: "I killed him" and "I didn't kill him" are negatives.

Comment: something like "kill" => "unkill"?

Comment: @holydragon No, I mean: "I killed him" and "I didn't kill him", they are negatives.

Comment: Such a verb would be effectively meaningless, wouldn't it? What does it mean to do X if you can't *not* do X?

Comment: Why do you say  "I killed him" is negative?  Killing someone isn't negative in a grammatical sense. It might not even be negative in reality - for example if they were saving them from intractable pain (euthanasia).

Comment: *"To be or not to be, that is the question"*   Are there really an verbs that are like this in your own native language?

Comment: @chaslyfromUK I mean they are negatives of each other. A = ~B and B = ~A

Comment: @MaciejStachowski your point is vary nice but I think there are some exceptions. for example I am living now and I can not "not living" now becuse I'm alive! but when we use "I'm not living" that is in the poetic way and doen't mean "I am not alive now". I'm wondering if there is a verb without use of negative form at all.

Comment: Please explain. Do you have a reason to believe there is such a verb or is this simply a puzzle you are setting us?

Comment: @chaslyfromUK it was a question from the literature teacher (if there is a verb like that or not). I think it is like a puzzle and I thought maybe someone here know the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A verb, by definition, is an action. You always have the option to not do any action. So no, there is no verb that cannot be used in the negative.